# UIAccessibility - Read all the labels and buttons on the screen from top to down

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiaccessibility

When view shows up only first label is being read, how can i make the app to read all the labels present on the screen without touching the screen so user can know what options are available?

Thanks

Comment: Providing requirements without showing any effort was once considered [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It is still [being debated now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215596/are-code-questions-without-an-attempt-now-on-topic), and many people consider it to be rude.

Comment: @Scott - It's very simple question so didn't add more requirements, can you please suggest what's missing?

Comment: Show some code, make your question clear and specific, generally try to follow ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), Oh and make it clear that you've given the problem some thought by sharing what you've tried so far.

Comment: Actually there is no code for UIAccessibility, it works when user enables it from settings.

Comment: @Paragon This is a strange requirement. Let usability work as intended. If the user wants to process the whole screen then the user will process the whole screen as they want. It would be really annoying if the app read the whole screen every time.

Comment: @rmaddy- i agree with you but i have only 3 labels in one screen that's where i just need to tell the user what options are available.
it's only for one screen

Comment: @Paragon Right but why make the user listen to all three every time? Again, keep your app standard. Other apps don't make a user listen to a whole screen. Users expect accessibility to work a certain way. Doing it differently would be a bad user experience.

Comment: @rmaddy Is it even possible?

Comment: The user can swipe up with two fingers and have all elements on the screen be read out in order. Isn't that what you are after? If the user want's to know what's on screen they will perform that gesture.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Exactly but can i perform the same action when screen shows up?

Comment: @Paragon I don't think you should (even if there was a nice way of doing so).

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist i totally agree with you guys but just for information is it even possible?

Comment: @Paragon Practically speaking, **no**. You cannot and should not force VoiceOver to behave in this way.