# Is there any way to have VoiceOver read a label on command?

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I'd like to have my QR code scanning app inform the user when it finds a QR code. For sighted users, this works using a label at the bottom that updates to notify the user. However, a blind user would have to tap on that label again to have it read by Voice Over. I would much prefer it to just read automatically.

The closest I can find to this question is
[UIAccessibility - Read all the labels and buttons on the screen from top to down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918480/uiaccessibility-read-all-the-labels-and-buttons-on-the-screen-from-top-to-down), which wasn't possible. While this doesn't bode well for my app, that was a year ago. Has Apple updated it's UIAccessibility protocol in any way to allow this?

As a last resort I suppose I could play my own mp3 recording if VoiceOver is on.

Comment: Have you tried https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccessibility_Protocol/#//apple_ref/c/data/UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can make VoiceOver speak any string any time you want by calling:

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification, NSLocalizedString("QR code has been detected", comment: ""))
```

**Swift 4**

```
UIAccessibility.post(notification: .announcement, argument: "Text")
```

There is no direct way to tell VoiceOver to speak updates of an element that VoiceOver cursor is not on. This (i.e. speaking the same content "manually") is a feasible workaround.

Answer (score 5):

You can move VoiceOver focus to an element by using the following:

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification, elementToFocusOn)
```

VoiceOver will then parse and read the accessibility properties associated with that element.